# How to fix E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical on Delphi?

Tags: delphi-2010

I wrote a own procedure which includes 2 arrays and a TextFile. On the form that I wrote it on it works, but when I try to use it on other forms this error message comes up.
I declared an array at type and both arrays in the procedure uses that type of array, but ons the other form it says that the arrays are not identical eventhough I declared it in exactly the same way.
Example of my code:

```
Form1
Type
Array = array[1..20] of string; //declaring the type of array
... 
Private
ArrUser : Array;
ArrPassword : Array;
tFile: TextFile;
... 
Var
Procedure Write(var tFile; var arrUser, ArrPassword : 
Array) ;
... 
Procedure Write(var tFile; var arrUser, ArrPassword : 
Array) ;
Var
Count, position, length : integer;
Line : string;
Begin
Count := 0;
AssignFile(tFile, 'sign in.txt');
Reset (tFile);
While NOT EOF(tFile) do
  Begin
     Inc(count) ;
     ReadLn(tFile, line) ;
     Position := pos(' ', line) ;
     Length := length(line) ;
     ArrUser[count] := copy(line, 1, position - 1);
     Delete(line, 1, position) ;
     ArrPassword[count] := line;
  End;
Closefile(tFile) ;
End;

Form2
Type
Array = array[1..20] of string; //declaring the type of array
... 
Private
ArrUser : Array;
ArrPassword : Array;
tFile: TextFile ;
... 
Begin
  Write(tFile, arrUser, ArrPassword) ; //error is shown here 
at the arrays
End;
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], and please format the code more cleanly. Once you have done this please also include the error message copied verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

### You are declaring two different array types.

Your procedure is expecting parameters of type `Form1.Array`, but you are passing it variables of type `Form2.Array` instead.  And you are passing the parameters by `var` reference, so the variables being passed *MUST EXACTLY MATCH* the type of the parameters. That is what the compiler error is complaining about.

Even if you were not using `var` references, the two array types are nonetheless still different types that are NOT [assignment compatible](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi)) with each other.

You need to get rid of one of the array types, and use the other array type in both units.  For example:

```
unit Form1;

interface

type
  Array = array[1..20] of string;

...
private
  ArrUser : Array;
  ArrPassword : Array;
...

Procedure Write(var tFile; var arrUser, ArrPassword : Array);

implementation

...

Procedure Write(var tFile; var arrUser, ArrPassword : Array);
begin
  ...
end;

...

end.
```

```
unit Form2;

uses
 ..., Form1;

...
private
  ArrUser : Form1.Array;
  ArrPassword : Form1.Array;
...

implementation

...

begin
  Write(tFile, ArrUser, ArrPassword) ;
end;

...

end.
```

For better maintainability, you should create a 3rd unit to declare the array type, and then `use` that unit wherever you need access to the array type.

```
unit MySharedUnit;

interface

type
  Array = array[1..20] of string;

implementation

end.
```

```
unit Form1;

interface

uses
  ..., MySharedUnit;

...
private
  ArrUser : MySharedUnit.Array;
  ArrPassword : MySharedUnit.Array;
...

Procedure Write(var tFile; var arrUser, ArrPassword : MySharedUnit.Array);

implementation

...

Procedure Write(var tFile; var arrUser, ArrPassword : MySharedUnit.Array);
begin
  ...
end;

...

end.
```

```
unit Form2;

uses
 ..., MySharedUnit, Form1;

...
private
  ArrUser : MySharedUnit.Array;
  ArrPassword : MySharedUnit.Array;
...

implementation

...

begin
  Write(tFile, ArrUser, ArrPassword) ;
end;

...

end.
```